# How to keep a textview within layout with drag and drop?

Tags: android, drag-and-drop

I try to use **drag and drop**  API in android.I have a `textview` in `linearlayout`.I want to keep this `textview` in layout. I prevent to the out of the `layout` when u dragging this `textview`.

How can I do that? I want to drag only `vertically` without `overflow`. I can drag and  drop exactly what I want. when I dragging, occurs overflow.
my codes:

```
 public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(view);
        view.startDrag(null, shadowBuilder, view, 0);
        view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

public boolean onDrag(View layoutview, DragEvent dragevent) {
    int action = dragevent.getAction();
    View view = (View) dragevent.getLocalState();

    int x=(int) dragevent.getX();
    int y=(int) dragevent.getY();

    if (x<0) {
        view.setX(0);
    }
    if (y<0) {
        view.setY(0);
        y=0;
    }
    if (y>0) {

        switch (action) {
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
                Log.d(LOGCAT, "Drag event started");
                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
                Log.d(LOGCAT, "Drag event entered into " + layoutview.toString());
                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
                Log.d(LOGCAT, "Drag event exited from " + layoutview.toString());
                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                Log.d(LOGCAT, "Dropped");

                ViewGroup owner = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
                owner.removeView(view);

                //only dragging vertically
                view.setY(dragevent.getY());

                LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout) layoutview;
                container.addView(view);
                view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
                Log.d(LOGCAT, "Drag ended");
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

I want to avoid `dragging` out of the `layout`. `TextView` width is `FILL_PARENT` so only can dragging vertically.
How can i do this ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Check this code out i got from a different answer

```
 public class OnDragTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {

/**
 * Callback used to indicate when the drag is finished
 */
public interface OnDragActionListener {
    /**
     * Called when drag event is started
     *
     * @param view The view dragged
     */
    void onDragStart(View view);

    /**
     * Called when drag event is completed
     *
     * @param view The view dragged
     */
    void onDragEnd(View view);
}

private View mView;
private View mParent;
private boolean isDragging;
private boolean isInitialized = false;

private int width;
private float xWhenAttached;
private float maxLeft;
private float maxRight;
private float dX;

private int height;
private float yWhenAttached;
private float maxTop;
private float maxBottom;
private float dY;

private OnDragActionListener mOnDragActionListener;

public OnDragTouchListener(View view) {
    this(view, (View) view.getParent(), null);
}

public OnDragTouchListener(View view, View parent) {
    this(view, parent, null);
}

public OnDragTouchListener(View view, OnDragActionListener onDragActionListener) {
    this(view, (View) view.getParent(), onDragActionListener);
}

public OnDragTouchListener(View view, View parent, OnDragActionListener onDragActionListener) {
    initListener(view, parent);
    setOnDragActionListener(onDragActionListener);
}

public void setOnDragActionListener(OnDragActionListener onDragActionListener) {
    mOnDragActionListener = onDragActionListener;
}

public void initListener(View view, View parent) {
    mView = view;
    mParent = parent;
    isDragging = false;
    isInitialized = false;
}

public void updateBounds() {
    updateViewBounds();
    updateParentBounds();
    isInitialized = true;
}

public void updateViewBounds() {
    width = mView.getWidth();
    xWhenAttached = mView.getX();
    dX = 0;

    height = mView.getHeight();
    yWhenAttached = mView.getY();
    dY = 0;
}

public void updateParentBounds() {
    maxLeft = 0;
    maxRight = maxLeft + mParent.getWidth();

    maxTop = 0;
    maxBottom = maxTop + mParent.getHeight();
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    if (isDragging) {
        float[] bounds = new float[4];
        // LEFT
        bounds[0] = event.getRawX() + dX;
        if (bounds[0] < maxLeft) {
            bounds[0] = maxLeft;
        }
        // RIGHT
        bounds[2] = bounds[0] + width;
        if (bounds[2] > maxRight) {
            bounds[2] = maxRight;
            bounds[0] = bounds[2] - width;
        }
        // TOP
        bounds[1] = event.getRawY() + dY;
        if (bounds[1] < maxTop) {
            bounds[1] = maxTop;
        }
        // BOTTOM
        bounds[3] = bounds[1] + height;
        if (bounds[3] > maxBottom) {
            bounds[3] = maxBottom;
            bounds[1] = bounds[3] - height;
        }

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                onDragFinish();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                mView.animate().x(bounds[0]).y(bounds[1]).setDuration(0).start();
                break;
        }
        return true;
    } else {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                isDragging = true;
                if (!isInitialized) {
                    updateBounds();
                }
                dX = v.getX() - event.getRawX();
                dY = v.getY() - event.getRawY();
                if (mOnDragActionListener != null) {
                    mOnDragActionListener.onDragStart(mView);
                }
                return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

private void onDragFinish() {
    if (mOnDragActionListener != null) {
        mOnDragActionListener.onDragEnd(mView);
    }

    dX = 0;
    dY = 0;
    isDragging = false;
}
  }
```

and you can set it using:

```
myView.setOnTouchListener(new OnDragTouchListener(myView));
```

Or by adding this directly in init method of your Custom View:

```
setOnTouchListener(new OnDragTouchListener(this));
```